# asp.net calendar control. Date selectable after 2 days from the current

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, calendar-control

Is it possible to restrict which dates are selectable in the calendar control eg so that a date can only be selected once it's at least two days ago?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @SteveWellens - I was hoping this would have been answered more easily by someone that actually works with ASP.NET, but since it hasn't been I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the calendar control's [`DayRender` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx) to control which days are visible/selectable (as seen in [this forum discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1085555.aspx/1)):

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date && e.Day.Date <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(2))
        e.Cell.Visible = true;
    else
        e.Cell.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I want to be visible but not selectable. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your page load:

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
```

Comment: I assume that he not only wants to select that date but to prevent that the user can select date earlier than the day after tomorrow(see M.Babcock link in his comment).