# How to only allow selection of dates two week from current date in a calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using asp.net Calendar control and I want to enable people to only select dates that are two weeks from the current date.

E.g. today's date is 06/01/2015. Can only select dates 20/01/2015 onwards. So if they select a date like 19/01/2015, it'll say error.

I've tried

```
 if ( Calendar1.SelectedDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)){

      Label8.Text = "*You can only select a date two weeks from now.";
      Label8.Visible = true;
   }
```

But there's an error. I've also tried the solution in

[asp.net calendar control. Date selectable after 2 days from the current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500882/asp-net-calendar-control-date-selectable-after-2-days-from-the-current)

but the error is the same.

> Error  1   'ASP.reservations_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged' and no extension method 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.reservations_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help would be appreciated!

-I'm using VS 2013, web form.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one bro:

```
 Calendar1.VisibleDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 20);
```

this will work :

```
  Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20);
```

Hope it works(sure it will):)

Comment: But i don't want it to just be today's date + 2 weeks that can be selected.

What if i want to select a date and the current date is 25 jan? I want to allow 25 jan + 2 weeks = 8 feb selection onwards!

Comment: oh ok this will help:

Comment: No no. I mean like.. As the days goes by, the selection is always current date + 2 weeks. How do i do that? So if i select a date 3 weeks later, I can only select a date that's 3 weeks later + 2 weeks, and i cannot select a date thats before that.

Comment: i can't get the idea here mate more explaning will help:/

Comment: like how do you want the result calender i understood that if the date where 1/1/2015 then the user cant select but dates from 1 --> 20 of the same mounth

Comment: hmm. basically i'm using a calendar for reservations, where people can do a reservation only if it's made at least two weeks in advance. does that help?

Comment: so what is the proplem?

Comment: but there's an error at the bottom as i mentioned :/